# non-interactive ssh session not finding command even though it is in the PATH

Tags: command-line, mac, ssh, path

I am trying to run a command via ssh on a server running mac os 10.9.5 with a command like

```
ssh server.address command
```

and am getting the error `bash: command: command not found`.

When I log in with an interactive session, everything works fine and the command is at a `/usr/local/bin/command`:

```
$ which command
/usr/local/bin/command
```

And when I ask for the non-interactive path via ssh from the client it includes `/usr/local/bin`:

```
$ ssh server.address "echo $PATH"
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/bin:/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@global/bin:/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.10/bin:/Users/me/anaconda3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Users/me/.rvm/bin
```

So I'm not sure why it's not finding the command (or any of the commands in `/usr/local/bin`)

I suspected it was because of those weird paths at the beginning of `$PATH` (like `/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10@global/bin`, but I can't find where those are being added to the path in the first place. I checked `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.profile`. Those ruby paths also aren't in the `PATH` when I log in interactively.

I'm not sure where to go from here. Using the full path for the command isn't an option because it is being called from another program. (Plus, this is certain to come up again if I can't get `/usr/local/bin` to be in my path).

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ ssh server.address "echo $PATH"
```

returns the $PATH of your **local shell** even though it is written from the remote one. The variable expansion in quotes is done before sending the command to the server. To get the remote path, you need to use

```
$ ssh server.address 'echo $PATH'
```

Comment: Ha. Well that's embarrassing. Mystery solved! (Though now I still need to figure out how to get `/usr/local/bin` into the server's PATH)

Comment: I would go the easiest way with calling the command with full path.

Answer (score 1):

So this is basically, as far as I can tell, a duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/351731/why-does-the-path-of-an-ssh-remote-command-differ-from-that-of-an-interactive-s

> From ssh(1) manual page: "If command is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell."
>
> So in short when you actually login to the machine bash is started as a login shell and loads the appropriate files, when you connect remotely and issue a command it is run in the place of bash, which means that these files do NOT load. You can work around it with using `su -l -c` or similar in the command part of ssh.

The simple answer is to use full paths to your files rather than those in the $PATH, easily found via using `which`

`which nano
/usr/bin/nano`

Comment: I had read that question, but what's strange in my situation is that `ssh server.address "echo $PATH"` shows that /usr/local/bin *is* in the PATH environment variable even for non-login, non-interactive shells.

This is especially a problem for me because the ssh call is in a program that I can't edit, so I can't specify a full path.